# iPython giving me a syntax error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ipython

I'm running python 2.4 right now and have installed iPython onto my ubuntu machine. 
The problem I'm having right now is that it keeps giving me an ImportError whenever I try to launch it from the terminal.

Right now the symbolic link is located `/usr/local/bin` and the actual file is inside `/usr/bin/`

Error Message:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9
except ImportError as e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

iPython File...

```
#!/opt/ttools/bin/python ## YES THIS IS THE CORRECT PATH
"""Terminal-based IPython entry point.
"""

from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance

try:
  launch_new_instance()
except ImportError as e:
  if "qt.console.qtconsoleapp" in e.message:
    print "Could not start qtconsole. Please install ipython-qtconsole"
  elif "html.notebook.notebookapp" in e.message:
    print "Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook"
  else:
    # if there is no clue on the cause -- just re-raise
    raise
```

I've never had an issue like this when I had to set it up on my mac...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!

EDIT :: SOLUTION

Download http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.10.2/ipython-0.10.2-py2.6.egg

navigate to downloads folder and run the following command:

`sudo easy_install ipython-0.10.2-py2.6.egg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPython dropped support for python < 2.6 since version 0.11, you'll have to install 0.10 (or possibly even 0.9) from the archive:

http://archive.ipython.org/release/

Comment: thanks for your help Pavel... Now I'm getting an error where there is 'No module named IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp' Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I changed my answer. How did you get python 2.4? What ubuntu is this?